# Blacklisted Kernel Module pcspkr, Now I Can't Undo And Have No Sound

Tags: centos

I just installed CentOS 8 to try it. I use tab completion a lot in the terminal and the beeping noise was getting on my nerves a little bit. I decided to turn it off temporarily. I first tried blacklisting the kernel module `pcspkr` in `/etc/modprobe.d`.

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/bell.conf
blacklist pcspkr
$ shutdown -r now
```

After the reboot, I still had the beep sound which seemed odd. I spent a little time on google and found that there might be other things controlling the beep. Next I tried modifying my dconf settings.

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedback-sound "false"
$ shutdown -r now
```

This time the beep/bell sound was gone. Unfortunately, so was all other sound... :(

So I did what any sane person would do and reversed both of the changes mentioned above.

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedback-sound "true"
$ shutdown -r now
```

No sound

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/modprobe.d/bell.conf
$ shutdown -r now
```

No sound

I've checked in the settings (GUI) and all sound sources are turned on (i.e. Output and Sound Effects) and volume is turned up to at least 50%.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I can always just do a fresh installation to fix this, but I am curious what actually is going on here and how I can fix it without re-installing.

---

#### Update

Over the past few days, I have been trying different things to see if I could get any sound with no luck. When I sat down tonight to play with it for the last time before I was just going to give up and reinstall, I got the sound to work...kind of.

So If I go into the sound settings and change the volume for output and/or sound effects, nothing changes. I don't have any sound. If I change the sound effect alert sound I also do not get any sound. Now if I go to the output tab and click the `test speakers` and test either the left or right speaker, I hear a little noise almost like when you plug or unplug headphone jacks or a microphone with the sound up really loud. After that all noises work just fine including the terminal beep.

If I reboot, it reverts to no sound until I do the above steps again. Any ideas what might be going on here? I'm thinking it may have something to do with the kernel module not fully loading until its explicitly requested maybe via the test speakers code behind the scenes.

Comment: Try to manually load the module with `sudo modprobe pcspkr` and check with `sudo lsmod` and `sudo dmesg` to make sure it is loaded and there are no errors. Are there any? Then, in `bash`, does a `echo -e '\a'` output any sound?

Comment: So I did try manually loading the module using `sudo modprobe pcspkr` and it did show up when doing `lsmod | egrep pcspkr`. I did not check dmesg for errors though. I'll double check that when I am at the machine in a few hours.

Comment: I can verify that there is no new `dmesg` output when I run `sudo modprob pcspkr`. I also tried logged in as `root`.